# Can you cascade simple wideband bandpass active filters?

Tags: filter

Can you cascade this type of active bandpass filter?. The bandpass filter type in the picture below seems to be the simplest type of an active bandpass filter. I am wondering if they can be cascaded like multiple feedback bandpass filters?  [image: simple active bandpass filter]

Comment: What are your specs overall? No reasons to deny cascading same BW

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'm just comparing the difference between this type of filter vs a multiple feedback , and obviously the above filter is more wider. I was just playing around with a spice program and making bandpass filters in an random audio frequency range to see what would happen if you cascaded them. Obviously if you cascade multiple-feedback filters you can get different types of filters like Butterworth etc., cascading simple filters only seem to get slightly narrower stopband and lowered gain. Doesn't seem possible to make a Butterworth type filter with the simple active bandpass.

Answer (score 0):

The cascaded 1st order LP and HP can have separate breakpoints and thus a wide plateau at some fixed gain at Av=R2/R1, if the breakpoints for LP are < HP.

While a 2nd order Bandpass, Multiple Feedback, Butterworth will always be 2nd order HPF and LPF sharing the same breakpoint with  R2/R1 not = Av but must increase by 6 dB to compensate for the -3dB loss in each LP,HP shared breakpoint.  But here a Butterworth 2nd order BP filter is possible but then there is no plateau in the mid-band.

They can never be the same filter as yours is two cascaded 1st order filters.

But with more complexity you can achieve dual 1st order HP LP filters with 1 capacitor, but it's not worth the trouble.

Although this is not what you asked for, I thought it demonstrates the fundamental advantages yet differences in "order" of each type of filter slope. Yes all can be cascaded within **reasonable specs** that must be defined 1st BEFORE ANY DESIGN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cascading means convolution, and repeated convolution converges towards a Gaussian, which means a bell-shaped curve, not a flat plateau. it doesn't matter how far apart the edges are, that wil be the point of convergence (after sufficient stages).

One other reason has to do with the type of filter that you have there: a bandpass derived from a first order lowpass prototype. That filter will never have complex poles, therefore the Q for each, independent stage will never be greater than 0.5.

When you calculate a MFB filter of any kind (Butterworth,Chebyshev, Papoulis, Halpern, there are a ton of classical filter design) that implies a transfer function that is specifically designed to have passband flatness within prescribed requirements. The resulting transfer function will be taylored specifically to meet those requirements. You cannot achieve that with a 1st order derived bandpass, and certainly not with several such filters, cascaded.

In fact, you could try this for a (possible) eye opener: try making a 4th order bandpass (that is, the transfer function should be 4th order), of any kind, and see how the individual 2nd order stages respond. Compare that with 2 stages as in the OP. I was tempted to post some screenshots, but I'll leave it to you to discover.